# How to stop refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh

Is there any chance to stop the page to refresh on every pressed `control`?

For example: I change the selection of a `DropDownList` and the page refreshes. It just feels weird.

I do it with a form tag `runat="server"`

Comment: Turn `autopostback=false`

Comment: Try update panel it would helps you!

Comment: @TFrost it will stop his code running on `SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Then you can use updatepanel

Comment: @TFrost making  autopostback=false wont enable SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: why use heavy asp.net webform controls? why not just use html controls and make use of ajax?

Comment: @dahsra : that's the reason I said the OP can use updatepanel, without changing any `control's` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`UpdatePanel`](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx) and here you can find [`how to use the update Panel`](http://code.runnable.com/UhmIdrdIZy9aAATR/how-to-use-updatepanel-in-asp-net) sample code.

easiest way to stop refeshing

**Regarding PostBack:**
PostBack is the name given to the process of submitting an ASP.NET page to the server for processing. PostBack is done if certain credentials of the page are to be checked against some sources (such as verification of username and password using database). This is something that a client machine is not able to accomplish and thus these details have to be 'posted back' to the server.

**What is `AutoPostBack` Property in ASP.NET:**

If we create a web Page, which consists of one or more Web Controls that are configured to use `AutoPostBack` (Every Web controls will have their own `AutoPostBack` property), the ASP.NET adds a special JavaScipt function to the rendered HTML Page. This function is named `_doPostBack()` . When Called, it triggers a PostBack, sending data back to the web Server.

[Understanding PostBack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811684/Understanding-The-Complete-Story-of-Postback-in-AS)

**Try putting update panel for dropdown with triggers**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSetSession" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMyList" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ddlMyList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Maybe</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMyList" 
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax):

> Perhaps the most visible feature of the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions is the ability to do a partial or incremental page updates without doing a full postback to the server, with no code changes and minimal markup changes. The advantages are extensive – the state of your multimedia (such as Adobe Flash or Windows Media) is unchanged, bandwidth costs are reduced, and the client does not experience the flicker usually associated with a postback.

Integrate partial rendering into your project. Have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax) link.

Also `OnClientClick="return false;"` may help but adding `OnClientClick="return false;"` on every button, is not a good idea. Partial rendering and AJAX is the better solution.